# selenium: @id=contains(., won't work with xpath for radio button

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, xpath

I have a list of radio buttons, each labeled by color. This selects a single radio button labeled `Red`, the third option:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='600,-2147649943:1107:Red||_tr']//input[@name='doc_type']").click()
```

I want to be able to select other entries like `Blue` or `Green`. Each color's id has a unique number for the `'600,-2147649943:1107` field, and I need an xpath string that I can plug variable text into.
So I try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id=contains(.,'Red')]//input[@name='doc_type']").click()
```

This selects the first option on the radio list, which does not contain the characters `Red` anywhere in it. There compiler shows no errors.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: It's normal for your compiler not to detect this issue since it's a logical one. Your compiler should catch system issues like using function names that do not exist or others. The compiler cannot catch as I said logical issues. But who knows. AI is running like crazy. Maybe in the future, the compiler will also know what you want, and find it out haha. Hope that I helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your XPath (syntax error) :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'Red')]//input[@name='doc_type']").click()
```